# ¿Cómo resuelvo el error "node:internal/crypto/hash:71 this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);" al hacer npm run dev?

Tags: javascript, laravel, electron

estoy creando un proyecto con electron y laravel. El problema está en que quiero ejecutar node_modules y hago npm run dev dentro de una carpeta pero me manda este error:

```
node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);   
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19) 
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)     
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (C:\Users\Rappe\OneDrive\Escritorio\boombang-2009-app\www\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:145:18)  
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.digest (C:\Users\Rappe\OneDrive\Escritorio\boombang-2009-app\www\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:80:21)        
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Rappe\OneDrive\Escritorio\boombang-2009-app\www\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:874:53)
    at C:\Users\Rappe\OneDrive\Escritorio\boombang-2009-app\www\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:914:10
    at C:\Users\Rappe\OneDrive\Escritorio\boombang-2009-app\www\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

He visto que se puede solucionar bajando la versión de node y npm; sin embargo los archivos dejan de funcionar.

Comment: Que version de `node` estas usando?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar agregando `NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider'` al inicio de tu script `dev` dentro de `package.json`:

```json
"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' ..."
```

Este problema es debido a distintas versiones de OpenSSL, Node 17+ usa OpenSSL 3, pero no esta completamente soportado por muchos paquetes NPM.

Aca esta la información en el blog oficial de NodeJS: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v17.0.0/#openssl-3-0

Answer (score 2):

Comprueba que la versión de Node coincide con la del proyecto.
Yo tenía la versión 19 de node y el proyecto la versión 16. Actualicé a la versión 16 y me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Usa NVM para instalar diferentes versiones de node. Así será más fácil notar con cuál funciona. Este error me dejó de aparecer cuando empecé a usar la 14.18.3, y el proyecto ionic compiló la app.